# Quantifying an increasing spacing between data points

Tags: st.statistics, data-analysis, time-series

Is there a measure or statistic that could quantify a steady increase in the spacing between data points in a time series?

For instance, in the figure, the points are clustered and dense near 0, but then they become more and more sparse.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: by "variance" I think you mean "spacing", so the time dependence of the mean spacing should give you the information you want.

Comment: Hi Carlo, thank you for the precision. That's what I meant! Is there any reference or formulation that you know of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is the [inhomogeneous Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Inhomogeneous_Poisson_point_process) with rate $\lambda(t)$.

In this graph from Wikipedia the rate is increasing then decreasing; in your case it would be everywhere decreasing.
[image]